# How draw a line dynamically using manipulate?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, dynamic

I want to paint a curve on a sphere while I’m manipulating stereoscopic projection points on the plane with a 2D slider, but I’m having trouble collecting the points needed to create the Line primitives. The example script merely tries to collect some points and draw a line on the same plane. The two lines pertaining to collecting the points and plotting the line are commented out because they produce looping or deep recursion. I’ve tried Append[] and Reap[Sow[]] in a number of rearrangements. Nothing turned up for me in searches, but if you know the right vocabulary for a query, you probably already know the solution. Any ideas?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Manipulate[
(*curve = Append[curve, pt];*)

Graphics[{
    {Red,PointSize[.02],Point[pt]}
    (*Line[curve]*)
},
Axes->True,
AxesLabel->{Style["x",Bold,16],Style["y",Bold,16]},
PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1}},
Background->White,ImageSize->Medium],

{{pt,{0.0,0.0},Style["Move the point on the plane.",Bold,16]},{-1,-1},{1,1}},

Initialization:> (curve ={{0.0,0.0}})
]
```

Comment: Use the option `TrackedSymbols->{pt}`?

Comment: Perhaps you want locators with LocatorAutoCreate

Comment: What do you mean looping/deep recursion? It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @Pickett, does it work fine uncommented? I want a curve to follow what is now a point.

Comment: @GaryPalmer Yes, that is exactly what happened for me when I uncommented your code. Although you need a comma before the `Line[curve]`.

Comment: After reading @Pickett's comment, I removed the comments and tried it, and now it works for me for the first time, though there is an annoying flickering in the cell tag on the right. But maybe it will be OK. I may have been distracted from success by some seemingly unfavorable diagnostic output.

Comment: @GaryPalmer, if you add the option `TrackedSymbols->{pt}` to your `Manipulate`  flickering goes away..

Comment: So apparently the problem was a non-problem, but perhaps there are nicer approaches that will appear soon, perhaps something with Reap and Sow that might offer more speed in more complex situations. Otherwise, I leave it to the monitors to decide what to do with it. I will look into the suggestions of kguler and belisarius.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done more cleanly by localizing `curve` to the manipulate, which in turn is done by making `curve` an invisible control. This also obviates the need for the `Initialization` option, because controls take optional initializers.

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[{
    {Red, PointSize @ .02, Point@pt},
    Line @ AppendTo[curve, pt]}, 
    Axes -> True, 
    AxesLabel -> {Style["x", Bold, 16], Style["y", Bold, 16]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
    ImageSize -> Medium], 
  {{pt, {0.0, 0.0}, Style["Move the point on the plane.", Bold, 16]}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}},
  {{curve, {{0.0, 0.0}}}, None},
  TrackedSymbols -> {pt}]
```

[image: pt-path]

Comment: Thank you for bringing me this fact in mind again, I forgot to try it.(+)

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the Set in Initialization by a SetDelayed solved the problem,
TrackedSymbols should be set also.

Conjecture:
It seems Clear before Manipulate produces problems, I can't believe it. It can be used in a separate cell, but not in the same cell. Experiences?

```
Manipulate[

 curve = Append[curve, pt];
 Graphics[{{Red, PointSize@.02, Point@pt}, Line@curve},
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {Style["x", Bold, 16], Style["y", Bold, 16]},
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
  Background -> White,
  ImageSize -> Medium],

 {{pt, {0.0, 0.0}, 
   Style["Move the point on the plane.", Bold, 16]}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}},
 Initialization :> (curve := {{0.0, 0.0}}) (* := *),
 TrackedSymbols -> {pt}]
```

[image: movePoint2D]

Comment: as with Pickett's experience and with TrackedSymbols I no longer see a problem. SetDelayed actually breaks it.

Comment: did you see how I simplified your first line in Graphics, using the `@` symbol makes the code easy readable, avoiding brackets and parenthesis is a good strategy, but needs a good knowledge on syntax too. `Clear` is no more necessary. `TrackedSymbols` is good, but not necessary.

Comment: sorry I missed a ")" corrected now

Comment: The Point[{pt[[1]],pt[[2]]}] rather than Point[pt] resulted from paring down a 3D script. It is also fixed.

Comment: What MMA version do you use?

Comment: MMA 10 Home Edition